# THREE.JS: why is the rotation only applied on the last axis used?

Tags: rotation, matrix, three.js

my function:

```
    function rotateAroundWorldAxis2(object, radians1, radians2) {


        object.rotWorldMatrix.makeRotationX(radians1).makeRotationZ(radians2);
       // object.rotWorldMatrix;

        // old code for Three.JS pre r54:
        //  rotWorldMatrix.multiply(object.matrix);
        // new code for Three.JS r55+:
        object.rotWorldMatrix.multiply(object.matrix);                // pre-multiply

        object.matrix.copy( object.rotWorldMatrix );

        // old code for Three.js pre r49:
        // object.rotation.getRotationFromMatrix(object.matrix, object.scale);
        // old code for Three.js pre r59:
        // object.rotation.setEulerFromRotationMatrix(object.matrix);
        // code for r59+:
        object.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(object.matrix);

    }
```

my object was initialized like this:
object.rotWorldMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

Answer (score 1):

Calling "makeRotationX/Y/Z" will fill up the matrix cells with values for rotation around the wanted axis, thus overriding any previous value in the matrix.

According to example [here](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Matrix4), you should instead build one separate matrix per rotation axis then at the end multiply those matrices in a single final one.

So in your case it would look like :

```
var mX = new THREE.Matrix4();
mX.makeRotationX(radians1);

var mZ = new THREE.Matrix4();
mZ.makeRotationZ(radians2);

var m = new THREE.Matrix4();
m.multiplyMatrices( mX, mZ );

object.rotWorldMatrix.copy(m);

object.rotWorldMatrix.multiply(object.matrix); 

//...
```

Note that depending on the order you use to multiply matrices you may get different result, this is called the "gimbal lock" problem but this is another vast subject, I will not discuss it here...